# $||\underline{x}+\underline{y}||= ||\underline{x}-\underline{y}||$ implies x is perpendicular to y.

Tags: inner-products

Let $(X,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be an inner product space. Prove if $X$ is a real vector space, then  $\lVert x+y\rVert= \lVert x-y \rVert$ implies $x\perp y$.

Comment: Please use Latex for improved readability!

Comment: Hint: what is the norm with respect to the inner product?

Comment: @freak_warrior: also, try to use *proper* LaTeX. $<$ is not a triangular bracket, it's inequality sign, and $||$ is not the correct way to write a norm (wrong spacing).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** we can write
$$
\|x+y\|^2 = \|x-y\|^2 \implies
\langle x+y,x+y\rangle = \langle x-y,x-y\rangle
$$
Using the linearity of an inner-product, expand the above.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\|x+y\|^2=\langle x+y,x+y \rangle$ and $\|x-y\|^2=\langle x-y,x-y \rangle$ then if they are equal you obtain $$\langle x,x\rangle +\langle y,y \rangle + \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,x\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle +\langle y,y \rangle - \langle x,y \rangle - \langle y,x\rangle  $$ and so $$2\langle x,y\rangle = -2\langle y,x\rangle .$$

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of norms
$$\|x+y\|^2 = \|x-y\|^2 \implies
\langle x+y,x+y\rangle = \langle x-y,x-y\rangle.
$$

Simplifying, we'll get
$$\langle x,y\rangle=0$$

Comment: This is exactly the same as Omnomnomnom's answer. His was two minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The parallelogram spanned by $x$ and $y$ has equal diagonals, hence it is a rectangle.  “Elementary, Watson.”